# How can I use XPath with AS3 and get a result that still reffereced to the XMLDocument object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, xpath

I'm parsing a XML string into XMLDocument object. I want to search for a specific node using XPath technology by using `XPathQuery.execQuery()` - this function returns new XML object which means I need to convert it to a different XMLDocument object and lose the reference, how can I do that without loosing the reference?

I'm using this [XPath library](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/) of AS3.

Comment: What is tying you to `XMLDocument`? XML processing has improved a lot in AS3 with the e4x enabled `XML` class. Searching for a specific node can be done as easily as `xml..somenode(@id == "3")` (this returns a `somenode` element somewhere in the hierarchy that has an `id` attribute whose values is 3).

Comment: Can it run XPath queries? Can it return siblings of a specific node?

Comment: Apparently it can: http://wso2.org/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amarghosh has a good point. why aren't you using e4x ? here is the livedocs documentation for it http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_01.html