# Is there an Actionscript library that can be used to target Flex components in the display list using an xpath-like syntax?

Tags: apache-flex, path, find, components, xpath

I feel like I've seen something like this before, but not sure where and searches aren't turning up anything useful.  A library like this would evaluate xpath-like string expressions that would resolve to references to actual components (if they exist) in a Flex application's display list tree.

Comment: I don't know of anything.  In theory it could be created, but I'd be very cautious about the ues of something like this.  It seems like accessing your children's children would break encapsulation.

Comment: Agreed re. dangers of breaking encapsulation. Proposed use case is: an application's controller listens for generic UI events to bubble up the displaylist.  The controller differentiates between one component and another's event (e.g click) using the event's target.  To do this it must confirm that the event's target is the same as a reference the controller has to the view whose event it is interested in.  Yes, this can be hardcoded in a way that doesn't involve runtime evaluation.  But xpath-like syntax would result in more compact, flexible ways to reference views.

Answer (score 0):

these might help:

http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/wiki/GettingStarted

http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/xpath-with-as3/

http://apdevblog.com/actionscript3-e4x-and-xpath/

http://lab.arc90.com/2010/04/28/actionscript-3-xpath-library/

[How can I use XPath with AS3 and get a result that still reffereced to the XMLDocument object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608969/how-can-i-use-xpath-with-as3-and-get-a-result-that-still-reffereced-to-the-xmldoc)

Comment: how does it apply to searching the display list ?

Comment: Ditto.  Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: yeah, but its a good start to write own class of thing you want, so get the current UI classes and try to encapsulate them in your new class